# How to match an input value in Laravel match before saving to sqlite database

Tags: database, laravel, try-catch, response

I am trying to make the value of $input data to first match with one the pluck array values in a user table in the database before the input is saved and a response of 'its a match be given'. I trying to put these checks on an API I'm making. I'm new to laravel API and I will appreciate the help. Thank you

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request, [
            'inputed_number' => 'required|unique:users',
            'user_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        try {
            Auth::user();
            $phonenumber = new PhoneNumber();
            $phonenumber->inputed_number = $request->inputed_number;
            $phonenumber->user_id = $request->user_id;
            
            if($this->user->phonenumber()->save($phoneuumber)){
        $user = User::all();
        $input = $request->only('inputed_number');
        $user_number = $user->pluck('phone');
        foreach ($input as $phone) {
             if ($phone !== $user_number) {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'Invalid number',
                    'data' => $phone,
                ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }

            return response()->json([
                    'success' => true,
                    'message' => 'Its a match!!',
                    'data' => $phone,
            ]);
        }
    }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'You have already inputted this number.',
            ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just get the whole user object with Auth:user no need for the pluck statement, you can access values directly via user object,

```
$user = Auth:user();
 $input = $request->only('inputed_number');
if($user->phone !== $input ) {
   //perform this code
}
```

If you want to match phone numbers from all users,

```
//get all users where phone number matches
$users = User::where('phone', $input)->get();

// iterate through $users rows
foreach ($users as $user) {
    ///do some thing
}
```

Comment: I want to match the inputted phone number with all phone numbers already in the database. That is why I plucked the phone array so I can match it against the array list.

Comment: what are you getting in $users object, is there any error.

Comment: try this 
$users = User::where('phone',"=", $input)->get();

Comment: also check if input values is received correctly and in same format as in database

Comment: I keep getting an empty array for users. That is why I used the pluck instead which gave me an array of all phone numbers of users in the database.

Comment: in pluck your are asking to get all phone number in array, while in where condition you are comparing it with requested input, where(phone = input), so only if condition matches then data will be returned, other wise you will get empty data, that is why i am asking to check your input and database values

Comment: I think the problem is from the **$input** variable. I tried to console log it and it returned an null even though it saves in the database. The problem seems to be coming from this line: $input = $request->only('inputed_number');

Comment: Can you suggest any solutions to that?

Comment: try $request->input_number